# Subquery returns parsing error

Tags: soql, query, relationships

I am trying to fetch the currently logged in (customer portal) users details from their related contact field via SOQL.

I have created what I believe is the correct SOQL statement however I am receiving a parsing error

**SOQL**

```
SELECT id, contactid, (SELECT Name, Email, Phone FROM Contacts WHERE id = User.contactid) FROM User WHERE id = '005c000000112ZF'
```

Comment: If you replace `WHERE id = User.contactid` by `WHERE id =: User.contactid` ?

Comment: @SF_user nope its the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the dot notation to access the related Contact.

> select ContactId, Contact.Name, Contact.Email, Contact.Phone from User

For more regarding Salesforce relationships please check [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com)